# Reducing gap under \makecvtitle

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I use documentclass `moderncv` to write a resume. My question is how to reduce the vertical gap under the `\makecvtitle`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Smith} 

\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle 
% reducing gap between the title and section
\section{Education}
% reducing gap here
\section{Experience}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal working example that we can play with?

Comment: Try inserting a `\vspace{-1cm}` or so after `\makecvtitle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the definition of command `\makecvtitle` in file `moderncvheadii.sty` you can see, that there is an space added at the end of the command of `2.5em`.  Instead of changing `\makecvtitle` it is easier to add command `\vspace{-2.5em}` to get rid of this space (I **do not** recommend to do that!).

The gap between two sections is defined in command `\section` (see the both possibilitys to change the gap marked with `<======`, I reduced the gap by adding only `.5ex` instead of `2.5ex` for the first possibility):

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{.5ex}% <==================== change 2.5ex for your needs
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
  %            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <========= change value 1ex for your needs
```

In the following MWE we need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because the definition above uses an `@`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} % head 2, body 1, foot 1

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{.5ex}% <==================== change 2.5ex for your needs
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
  %            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  change value 1ex for your needs
\makeatother


\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Smith} 

\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle 
% reducing gap between the title and section
\vspace{-2.5em} % 1.25em 2.5em <====================================
\section{Education}
% reducing gap here
\cventry{year--year}{Degree-2}{Institution-3}{City-4}{\textit{Grade}-5}{Description-6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\section{Experience}
\section{Example}

\end{document}
```

results in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]